# Android multiple sync adapter items like Google Account?

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

I currently have my Android app set up to use the AccountManager feature of Android, using a SyncAdapter and an authenticated account to performs syncs automatically.

I only have 1 sync adapter running which syncs all content, but I would like to separate this out to performs syncs for different content at different intervals.

How can I have multiple sync items like Google does?

[image: Google account screenshot]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to define several sync adapters, using the same account type.

The manifest contains:

```
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.example.FooSyncAdapterService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter_foo" />
</service>
<service android:exported="true" android:name="com.example.BarSyncAdapterService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter_bar" />
</service>
```

And `syncdataper_foo` is

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="foo"
    android:accountType="com.example"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true" />
```

And `syncdataper_bar` is

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="bar"
    android:accountType="com.example"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true" />
```

Note that in the case of the account type "com.google", the sync adapters are even provided by different applications (Drive, Docs, Sheets, Gmail, Calendar, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before but your answer led me to notice you had a different contentAuthority for each SyncAdapter, this showed me the problem- there must be multiple ContentProviders, each registered to the contentAuthority specified in the SyncAdapter xml file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can i set label as at picture in question?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to just add up the main attribute which makes the sync type visible under accounts menu to the above answer.

**"android:userVisible="true"**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="foo"
    android:accountType="com.example"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true" 
    android:userVisible="true"/> // this line does the job of showing up.
```