# Why can I not install an app build with these two sync adapters?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to set up an app with two different sync adapters but the package installer isn't satisfied with my provider declaration. 
It says

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.daykm.tiger-1: Can't install because provider name com.daykm.tiger.mentions (in package com.daykm.tiger) is already used by com.daykm.tiger]
```

but I'm not seeing the conflict in provider name.

Here's the services and provider in the manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".sync.TimelineSyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/timelinesync" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".sync.MentionsSyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/mentionsync" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.daykm.tiger.sync.TwitterContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.daykm.tiger.timeline;com.daykm.tiger.mentions"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true" />
```

mentionsync.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/authority_mentions"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="false"/>
```

timelinesync.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/authority_timeline"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="false"/>
```

account_sync.xml holding strings for all the syncing stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="account_type">tiger.com</string>
    <string name="authority_timeline">com.daykm.tiger.timeline</string>
    <string name="authority_mentions">com.daykm.tiger.mentions</string>
    <string name="intent_name">database-change</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of allowParallelSyncs from False to True. You can also check out this link [Android multiple sync adapter items like Google Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998063/android-multiple-sync-adapter-items-like-google-account)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't create 2 sync adapters with the same `accountType`, try using two different values for the two sync adapters.

Comment: I figured that having multiple syncing servies is how you have multiple listings in the system menus,  System > accounts > accountType. Is that not how it works?